# C# Store salt used for the register to use on login

Tags: c#, security, xamarin.forms, hash, salt

I am making some kind of thinking problem.
I created a Register/Login system for my Xamarin.Forms app. Now when I register an account, I hash the password and add random salt, but I do the same for the login. The problem is that I need to get the exact same salt for the password that I used on the register.

Here are the 2 functions to create salt and hasing:

```
public String CreateSalt(int size)
{
    var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var buff = new byte[size];
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}

public String GenerateSHA256Hash(String input, String salt)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashstring =
        new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha256hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

And here is the code I use when registering and logging in:

```
async void btnLogInClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    string username = txtUsername.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    string salt = CreateSalt(16);
    string HashedPassword = GenerateSHA256Hash(password, salt);
    HashedPassword = HashedPassword.Replace('+', '-');
    HashedPassword = HashedPassword.Replace('/', '_');

    User user = new User
    {
        Username = username,
        Password = HashedPassword
    };

    var result =  await App.RestService.Login(user);
    if (result != null)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new SideMenuItems();
    }
}
```

How can I do that and still use a random salt for every new generated password?

Comment: Firstly, isn't it a bit unusual to hash and salt/hash the login? Are you referring the username/email?

Comment: I login with username and password. Now on the register page I salt/hash the password, but I do the same on the login.... The problem is that the password never match this way!

Comment: Share some of your code please. We need to know where you're at right now.

Comment: I added the code.... The login and register are almost the same, except for the function I am calling!

Comment: ... If processing is not an issue (as it should), you could probably symmetrically encrypt the salt in register and decrypt at login.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: The salt is not secret, you normally store its value unencrypted with the value of the hash. When you log in you look up the saved salt for the user and use it when validating the password.

Comment: Also just hashing the password and salt is not enough, you need to do it many, many times to be secure. Use a key derivation function like [system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8) it will handle things like salt and performing extra rounds of hashing for you.

Comment: Okay, but what if I create an account on one device and want to login on a different device. The device got different salts?

Comment: If you use different device, this value of salt will be different, you should store the value of salt to database, If User login in, we want to compare the hash value, we should get the value fo salt from database, then gerenerate the hash value , then compare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like every year I have to re-learn how to properly hash passwords. I just did that, and I'll do my best to explain here.

Your problem is that you are generating a new salt every time you call `CreateSalt`, when user logs in. As mentioned in the comments, you'll want generate the salt and hash once during registration, and save them to a database.

Then, when a user logs in, you can retrieve the salt from the database, and use it along with the password entered by the user to generate the hash.  Finally, you'll compare the newly generated hash with the hash saved in the database, to see if the password is correct.

I'd suggest using a slow hash algorithm and not SHA256 for generating the hash. PBKDF2 would be a good option, and comes built-in with .NET as the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8) class. Another popular option is bcrypt. It necessitates a third-party library in .NET, but I find it to be easy to implement (at least with Node). More general info on password hashing algorithms [here](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/).

One last thing to consider is the number of iterations the algorithm uses. The `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class has a few constructors, one of which sets a default of 1000 iterations, which should be sufficient. The iterations (or "cost") slows the hash function and helps thwart attacks.